# How to rebase messy local git history

Tags: git, rebase

My overall goal is to reword the commit message of a previous commit, however, between the previous commit and now, I've branched & merged, causing problems for git rebase -i.

The commit history right now is extra wacky, because on a previous attempt to rebase -i and fix the message, I skipped failed rebases, deleted my history, and then had to merge a dangling commit found via git reflog.  I'm still fairly new to git, so I apologize for any noobiness.

How can I take this history and make it linear so I can rebase -i back to the original commit and reword the message?

I've attached a graph of my git history.

[git history graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8F2d.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
# Determine the index of the commit you want to rebase to. 
  git log

# Reset the index to the desired commit
  git reset --hard <commit>
```

Now that the head is pointing where you want,

```
# Rebase
  git rebase master develop
```

Comment: 1. what is 'develop' ? is that a keyword, or is it supposed to refer to a branch?  2. Also, in the picture I linked, can you explain to me what original/refs/head/master is? Why is it  different from master, and what would have split them originally? -- also, i'm waiting to understand this a little better before I implement your solution and potentially upvote you

Comment: `develop` is a branch name. It is advisable not to mess with the `master`. Always work on a different branch and when you are confident with your code, create a pull request and merge it to the `master`. 

`refs/original/*` is there as a backup, in case you mess up your filter-branch. Once you've inspected the results, and you're very confident that you have what you want, you can remove the backed up ref:

`git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master`

Comment: @KMongiello Glad I could help